# Xpath: How to get text located outside of any html tag

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="inner_container">
       This is <strong>text</strong> I don't want to extract.
   </div>
</div>
<br/>This is the text I'd like Xpath to extract
```

Using xpath, how can I extract "This is the text I'd like Xpath to extract"

Comment: This is in fact invalid HTML. The main problem is that there is no root element, in fact there are two `<div class="container">` and `<br/>`. Might not be possible to use XPath here. Or is this just a fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the provided HTML is just a fragment and there is a single root element, the text can be selected by the following XPath expression:

```
//br/following-sibling::text()[1]
```